# Live sql oracle integrity constraint error, primary key not found

Tags: sql, oracle

fairly new to sql not sure why this error is coming up, i'm asked to use alter to add columns and foreign key to the animal table referencing the species table species name. i can't figure out a way around this, any help is appreciated. thanks :)

here's my drop tables and create tables query:

```
DROP TABLE AnimalSale;

DROP TABLE Animal;

DROP TABLE Customer;

DROP TABLE Species;

CREATE TABLE Animal(   
   animalID NUMBER(4),   
   animalName VARCHAR2(50), 
   PRIMARY KEY (animalID) 
);

CREATE TABLE Customer(   
   custID NUMBER(4),   
   custName VARCHAR2(50),   
   custEmail VARCHAR2(50),   
    PRIMARY KEY (custID)   
);

CREATE TABLE AnimalSale(      
    animalID NUMBER(4),      
    custID NUMBER(4),      
    PRIMARY KEY (animalID, custID)   
);

CREATE TABLE Species(   
    speciesCode NUMBER(6),   
    speciesName VARCHAR2(30) UNIQUE,   
    speciesPrice DECIMAL(5,2),   
    PRIMARY KEY (speciesCode)   
);
```

My alter query, my lecturer told me the constraint part is wrong but i still couldn't figure out what's wrong and she's not giving me answer :(

```
ALTER TABLE Animal ADD speciesName VARCHAR2(30);

ALTER TABLE Animal ADD CONSTRAINT fk_species_name FOREIGN KEY (speciesName) REFERENCES Species(speciesName);
```

Insert table query:

```
INSERT INTO Animal (animalID, animalName, speciesName) VALUES( '1', 'Tiny', 'Dog');

INSERT INTO Animal (animalID, animalName, speciesName) VALUES( '2', 'Prince', 'Dog');

INSERT INTO Animal (animalID, animalName, speciesName) VALUES( '3', 'CJ', 'Cat');

INSERT INTO Animal (animalID, animalName, speciesName) VALUES( '4', 'Sid', 'Cat');

INSERT INTO Animal (animalID, animalName, speciesName) VALUES( '5', 'Sid', 'Snake');

INSERT INTO Animal (animalID, animalName, speciesName) VALUES( '6', 'Danger', 'Mouse');

INSERT INTO Animal (animalID, animalName, speciesName) VALUES( '7', 'Bonnie', 'Dog');

INSERT INTO Customer (custID, custName, custEmail) VALUES( '1', 'D.Smith', 'dsmith@yahoo.co.uk');

INSERT INTO Customer (custID, custName, custEmail) VALUES( '2', 'B.Bryne', 'bb@gmail.com');

INSERT INTO Customer (custID, custName, custEmail) VALUES( '3', 'X.Dobbs', 'xb@gmail.com');

INSERT INTO AnimalSale (animalID, custID) VALUES( '1', '1');

INSERT INTO AnimalSale (animalID, custID) VALUES( '2', '2');

INSERT INTO AnimalSale (animalID, custID) VALUES( '3', '2');

INSERT INTO AnimalSale (animalID, custID) VALUES( '4', '3');

INSERT INTO AnimalSale (animalID, custID) VALUES( '5', '2');

INSERT INTO Species (speciesCode, speciesName, speciesPrice) VALUES ('1', 'Dog', '9.99');

INSERT INTO Species (speciesCode, speciesName, speciesPrice) VALUES ('2', 'Cat', '10.20');

INSERT INTO Species (speciesCode, speciesName, speciesPrice) VALUES ('3', 'Snake', '20.00');

INSERT INTO Species (speciesCode, speciesName, speciesPrice) VALUES ('4', 'Mouse', '5.00');
```

Comment: What was the exact text of the question (not your paraphrasing of the question)? From what you have said, the DDL statements are fine - the error is in the order of your `INSERT` statements but this does not match up with where you stated that the lecturer said the problem was. You may need to go back to the lecturer and tell her that you don't quite understand where the problem was and ask for their help to understand it.

Comment: Peter has decided that he wants to record the species of each animal. To do this you need to introduce a species
table. The animal table will need a column added to it to record the species of each animal. This will be a foreign
key.
a. Create the species table (based on the description below)
b. Make the necessary changes to the Animal Table (add the column and the foreign key using ALTER)
c. Insert the data into the species table
d. Update the animal table (using the data below)
Species Table: Primary Key: speciesCode.

Comment: this was the question, but i think i was getting the wrong idea on how the foreign key referencing work. it was my bad on stating it has to be the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i'm asked to use alter to add columns and foreign key to the animal table referencing the species table species name

The error I get when running your script is:

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (FIDDLE_LVXOXDENESSERWXORCJT.FK_SPECIES_NAME) violated - parent key not found

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=eb1552d6a961c68827bc87e5c05897c0)

To solve it, I just swapped the order of the insert statements so that values were inserted in to the `species` table before you try to insert values into the `animal` table so that the foreign key reference can be satisfied.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=837ac71abc1937a9998b1eb45f3519fe)

*Note: the `INSERT` statements were wrapped in an anonymous PL?SQL block just for simplicity and so they could all be executed in a single statement; you could equally run each individually.*

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, or might be your lecturer wants the `animal` table's foreign key to refer primary key of `species` table.

Do this:

```
ALTER TABLE Animal ADD species_FK NUMBER(6);

ALTER TABLE Animal ADD CONSTRAINT fk_species_id FOREIGN KEY (species_FK) REFERENCES Species(speciesCODE);
```

In `insert`, use the `speciescode` from `species` table into your animal table's newly added column.

Cheers!!

Comment: The OP states "i'm asked to use alter to add columns and foreign key to the animal table referencing the species table species name" so adding a reference to the `PRIMARY KEY` is not what they've been asked to do (and they can use the `UNIQUE` constraint to reference). But, I do agree that it would make sense to use the primary key rather than a name.

Comment: but i focused more on "my lecturer told me the constraint part is wrong but i still couldn't figure out what's wrong "

Comment: thank you so much,  and yes using the primary key would be better, it was my bad since i can't get my head around, i was trying to reference the names, then when selecting the tables i would display the id column. but i guess that's just making things more complicated.  :)